# Rails Turbolinks mixing up my slider when site is reached via link

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

My slider looks totally normal after a normal page load (ie. refresh or opened for first time), but when you follow a link to go to the page where the slider is, it messes up. I am blaming Turbolinks for this. It really makes my website go faster, so I wouldn't want to give it up.

The project I'm working on is on Rails, obviously.

This is how it normally looks like:

[image: Normal slider]

and this is what it looks like when you follow a link to view the page

[image: Broken slider]

I am using Tinycarousel for the slider: https://baijs.com/tinycarousel/

I do not really know what to try because this is the first time I am using Rails, therefore I'm pretty stuck on this one without any options how to continue.

This is the CSS for the slider:

```
/* Tiny Carousel */
#latest-products { height: 1%; margin: 30px 0 0; overflow:hidden; position: relative; padding: 0 50px 10px;   }
#latest-products .viewport { height: 235px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
#latest-products .buttons {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 0;
    width: 46px;
    height: 70px;
    color: $d_deep_red;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 50px;
    transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
#latest-products .next {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    top: 20%;
}

#latest-products .buttons:hover {
    color: darken($d_deep_red, 10%);
}

#latest-products .disable { visibility: hidden; }
#latest-products .overview { list-style: none; position: absolute; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 240px; left: 0; top: 0; }
#latest-products .overview li{ float: left; margin: 0 30px 0 0; padding: 1px; height: 121px; border: 1px solid #dcdcdc; width: 236px;}
#latest-products .overview li img {border: 6px solid $d_caramel_orange;}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a page load without `turbolinks`. Simply add this to the `link_to` helper:

```
<%= link_to "link text", link_path, :"data-no-turbolink"=>true %>
```

This will cause the entire asset library to load for the specific link.

If you don't want that, and this is perfectly understandable, then you can add all `js` and `css` for the carussel (if it is specific for one view) to the view itself. Thus, they will load with the view and render normally.

**UPDATE - CORRECTION**: Removed final `s` from `data-no-turbolink`

Comment: I tried with the `link_to` code, but it's not giving me the desired result and the slider still shows up wrong after following the link. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly have you written? This code should be in every anchor linking to that page.

Comment: Yes, the link appears only once in my view and yet it's giving me problems. This is what I wrote exactly: `<%= link_to('Text here', { :controller => 'home', :action => 'index' }, 'data-no-turbolinks' => true) %>` and the output is correct on the HTML.

Comment: You should shoot me... Singularize to "data-no-turbolink" and you should be good to go... I'll correct my answer as soon as I get on a pc